# ReDim Preserve doesn't work vbscript

Tags: vbscript

I'm novice in vbscript,so don't be strict to me please.

I have this

```
    Dim positionArray
        positionArray = array()
set qwe = server.createobject("Scripting.Dictionary")
set parentListSorted= server.createobject("Scripting.Dictionary")
qwe = BuildClassificators(parentList,crntArtclId,parentListSorted,sum,positionArray)

Function BuildClassificators(parentList,curArtclId,parentListSorted,summary,posArray)

    Dim i,currentArtclId,items,keys
        items = parentList.Items
        keys = parentList.Keys       

    for i = 0 to parentList.Count - 1
            if (items(i) = curArtclId) then

                ReDim Preserve posArray(Ubound(posArray) + 1)
                posArray(Ubound(posArray)) = items(i)                      
                currentArtclId = keys(i)                                                                                               

                parentListSorted.Add currentArtclId,items(i)
                parentList.Remove currentArtclId                
            summary = summary + 1
      parentListSorted = BuildClassificators(parentList,currentArtclId,parentListSorted,summary,posArray)           
            else
                summary = 0
            end if
            if (i = parentList.Count - 1 And  summary = 0) then
            parentListSorted = BuildClassificators(parentList,posArray(Ubound(posArray)),parentListSorted,summary,posArray)
            end if
     next
    BuildClassificators = parentListSorted
End Function
```

The first problem that when I use ReDim Preserve posArray(Ubound(posArray) + 1) the third time my programm breaks(e.g. the first and the second time when needed it works).The programm just go out from function.What it may be?
And can anybody answer if I return function value rigth?
Thanks for the help.

Comment: UPD
I resolve the second question.To return value I need to use SET,e.g.
set BuildClassificators = parentListSorted 
instead of 
BuildClassificators = parentListSorted

Comment: UPD 2
I realy don't understand why I've got the first problem.So I replace array to arrayList and now it works.